# Proving conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have read in one tutorial that:

$P(A\cap B|C) = P(B|C)\cdot P(A|C)$

But to me this is quite strange:

I get:

$$    P(A\cap B|C) = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$$

Where $P(A,B,C)=P(A\cap B\cap C)$ can be evaluated according to chain rule:
    $$P(A|B,C) \cdot P(B|C) \cdot P(C)$$

so:

$$P(A\cap B|C) = P(A|B\cap C) \cdot P(B|C)$$

The only way the first equation is true, if $P(A|B,C) = P(A|C)$ ...
But how to prove that?

Comment: the first equation is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent (given $C$). What you got is always corret

Comment: @AsafRosemarin Yes they are independent in tutorial, but I am looking for an algebra solution, to derive and simplyfy it to get the same answer. Is this possible?

Comment: By definition of independence (given $C$) you get that $P(A \cap B | C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$ and we are done... Note that indepence given $C$ is not implied from independence - can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: @AsafRosemarin Yes, but how do we derive to definition?

Comment: That is the definition - there is nothing to derive

Answer (score 1):

Your statement isn't true in general without further assumptions.
Consider the sample space $S = \{1, 2\}$ with events $A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}$, and $C = S.$

Then $P(A, B\mid C) = 0$ but $P(B\mid C)P(A\mid C) = \dfrac{1}{4}$.